# php smarty if else loops not working

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, smarty

Basically i am putting some if elses for my array.

```
{if $array| count eq 0 || $array| count lt 10}
    <p>equal to 0, less than 10</p> 
{/if}
{if $array| count gte, ge 10}
    <p>greater than or equal to 10</p>
{else}
    <p>blah</p>
{/if}
```

Which is not working fine. So what could be the problem?

Comment: Tell us the problem. What do you mean by "not working fine"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this. you can use gte or ge, but not both.

```
{if $array| count lt 10}
 <p>equal to 0, less than 10</p> 
{/if}
{if $array| count ge 10}
 <p>greater than or equal to 10</p>
{else}
 <p>blah</p>
{/if}
```